# How to alter setup.py for CyIPOPT

Tags: python, ipopt

I want to install the python package CyIpopt (https://github.com/matthias-k/cyipopt) on windows 10 and python version 3.5.2. For the binary I am using http://www.coin-or.org/Binaries/Ipopt/Ipopt-3.10.1-Win32-Win64-dll.7z (which I unpacked). The github page gives install instructions. At one point it says:

> Download the source files of cyipopt and update setup.py to point to the header files and binaries of the Ipopt package, if LD_LIBRARY_PATH and pkg_config are not setup to find ipopt on their own.

I downloaded the source files from github and edited the setup.py file by altering lines 33-36 to :

```
IPOPT_ICLUDE_DIRS=['D:\...\Ipopt-3.10.1-Win32-Win64-dll\include\coin', np.get_include()]
IPOPT_LIBS=['IpOptFSS','IpOpt-vc10','IpOpt-vc8']
IPOPT_LIB_DIRS=['D:\...\Ipopt-3.10.1-Win32-Win64-dll\lib\\x64\Release MKL']
IPOPT_DLL=['IpOptFSS.dll','IpOpt-vc10.dll','IpOpt-vc8.dll']
```

The dots represent the path to these folders on my computer. Now when I run `python setup.py install`, it run succesfuly. However when I then run `python` and `import ipopt` I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\Users\Linthorst\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\ipopt-0.1.6-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\ipopt__init__.py", line 40, in 
>       from cyipopt import *
>   ImportError: No module named 'cyipopt'

I suspect I altered the setup.py file incorrectly (since I made an educated guess). I am confused that it installed but doesn't work. Can anybody help me solve this error? Many thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like a proper method to follow. We have an issue here: https://github.com/matthias-k/cyipopt/issues/21 tracking it. Not yet to the bottom of it.